# Getting Python error: Too many columns specified

Tags: python, pandas

I am running Python through conda and my terminal. I was given a script that should be able to run without error. The script imports a url and reads it as a csv. This is what I have been given:

```
url = 'https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hurdat/hurdat2.html'
data, storm, stormList = readHURDAT2(url)
columnnames= ['a,b,c,etc']
```

The error begins with the next line:

```
for line in pd.read_csv(url, header=None, names=columnnames, chunksize=1):
```

The computer runs several iterations before outputting this error message:

```
Too many columns specified: expected 20 and found 1
```

Comment: Might have something to do with `columnnames= ['a,b,c,etc']`.  That line implies that there is only a single column in the data.

Comment: You should include a minimal example of `pd.read_csv(url, header=None, names=columnnames, chunksize=1)`. e.g. `df=pd.read_csv(url, header=None, names=columnnames, chunksize=1); print(df.head(10).to_dict()`. Copy and paste it as text, format it as code

Comment: Would you please click on Edit below your question and add the `readHURDAT2` function definition? Also, is it `read_csv(URL, ...)` with `url` right? Looks like it should be one of `readHURDAT2` returned values. The thing is that the URL returns a HTML document, not a CSV document.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the data in https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hurdat/hurdat2.html is in HTML format. I'd recommend you copy and paste the data into a local CSV file and `read_csv` from it. Also, because [the file has a specific format](https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/hurdat/hurdat2-format.pdf) that splits the document into `HEADER LINES` and `DATA LINES`, both with a different number of columns, you'd need to set `engine='python'` to read it. Finally, there are the maximum of 21 columns, not 20.

The code should look something like this:

```py
for line in pd.read_csv('hurdat2.csv',   # <- Here
                        engine='python', # <- Here
                        header=None,
                        names=columnnames,
                        chunksize=1,
                        ):
```